# Why does substring ignore zeroes in casted integer?

Tags: java, parsing, substring

I am trying to get the last two and first two digits from a number. I am getting a really weird result with the return value of my `lastTwo` function.

```
public static int lastTwo(int digit){
  String str = Integer.toString(digit);
  String lastTwo = str.substring(str.length()-2);
  int response = Integer.parseInt(lastTwo);
  return response;
}
```

When the input `digit` is 104, the output of this is just `4`, but when the input is `114`, the output is `14` which is the correct output. Why is `substring` on `104` not returning a `0` in the correct place?

here is my bluej console just for extra visuals:

```
twoDigit.main({ }) (104)
4
10
twoDigit.main({ }) (114)
14
10
```

Comment: Keep result as `String` (do not convert to `int`).

Comment: return `String`, not `int`, to have `0` at the start

Comment: Because `int`s are _numbers_.  There's no difference between the number 04 and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is doing the splitting correctly, but primitive `int`s are not stored with leading zeroes; you can just return the `String` instead of `Integer.parse`ing it back to an `int`. e.g.

```
public static int lastTwoAsString(int digit){
  String str = Integer.toString(digit);
  String lastTwo = str.substring(str.length()-2);
  return lastTwo;
}
```

---

If you indeed want to parse it back to an `int`, Java won't print leading zeroes by default. However, you can print leading zeroes of an `int` using use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). Note that you must specify a width to use the `0` modifier, in this case `2` makes the most sense:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int value = lastTwo(104);
  String output = String.format("%02d", value);
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
04
```

Answer (score 3):

The last two digits of "104" is "04".
Then, the result of `Integer.parseInt("04")` is 4, because as an integer, the value of "04" is simply 4. And if you print the number 4, it's naturally printed as "4".

But why do you call `Integer.parseInt` at all?
The problem description seems underspecified.
It's not clear if the last two digits should be treated as a number or as a string.

If the last two digits should be a string, then your method should return a string.

If the last two digits should be a number, then instead of converting the input `int` to a `String`, it would be better to use the modulo operator:

```
static int lastTwo(int number) {
    return number % 100;
}

static String lastTwoAsString(int number) {
    String string = Integer.toString(number);
    return string.substring(string.length() - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current method signature returns an int. As such, it cannot return 02. You will have to change it to String or format the output where the method is called.

If you can change the return type to String, you can do:
First way:

```
public static String lastTwo(int digit) {
    String str = String.valueOf(digit);
    return = str.substring(str.length() - 2);
}
```

Otherwise, where you call the method, you can format it:

```
String.format("%02d", lastTwo(digit))
```